# Do soffit lights count as an exterior light required at doors?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I am considering installing soffit lights (if I can find a type that is decent quality) instead of wall mounted lights for my front door/porch area and for the front of the garage doors.  I know electrical code requires a light to be at each door, but would soffit lighting work for that requirement?

If so, should I be looking for a specific style of light that would install in my aluminum soffit or just look for a recessed fixture?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, soffit lighting will work. The requirement is just to provide adequate illumination outside at exterior doors.

Any recessed light should work.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to stay away from opinion based question - but any input on the style of fixture? For example, would a halo AT/IC recessed fixture work okay with a wet location rated halo LED trim/insert?  Or is there a specific line of products that are suitable for this?  I just wonder if using the exact same recessed light setup that I do in the kitchen is suitable for outdoors, inside the soffit.  The can depth may also become a problem.

Comment: Yes, it would work. Damp or wet location rated trim. The depth will have to be checked, but they also sell shallow fixtures.

Comment: Is there a suggested lumens for an exterior soffit light?  I am assuming 800-1,000...but then there is the idea that it may be too bright, especially if above a window.

Comment: I'm not sure about a suggested number, as it just depends on the location and just how bright you want it, but that 800-1000 sounds right. Probably a 60W comparable LED.

Comment: In a related context, Life Safety Code® NFPA 101(2015):7.8.1.3 specifies "at least 1 ft-cd (10.8 lux)", measured at the walking surface, for "egress lighting", where required by the corresponding occupancy chapter for designated egress paths. None is required for one- or two-family dwellings (in Chapter 24), but it gives you a starting point.

Comment: All, I did some measuring and I do NOT have enough room for a recessed fixture like I had thought.  My truss tails come down to my5.5" fascia board.  This means at the edge I have ~5.5" of clearance and at a 4/12 pitch I gain 4" per foot, meaning in my 20" soffit space, I have about 10" clearance close against the house wall, but as we know new construction recessed fixtures take up a good chunk of room.  Any thoughts? Maybe just the lotus lights that have the spring clips?

Comment: Try looking up the small 4" lights or shallow mounting lights. Some of those with it all built in might be your best bet.

Comment: Hey TFK, have you used those Lotus lights?  I am looking at Lithonia brand on Amazon.  About $32 a piece but they are very low profile with spring clips.  They look like the solution except I don't know how I'd remove them after the slip up in the soffit!  Prying them down would likely bend the aluminum soffit....

Comment: Normally the springs aren't that strong. You should be able to hold onto the soffit and gently pull down until you're able to push the springs back.

Comment: I guess my only concern now is having that little junction box that tails the light just float in the soffit or trying to mount it through the light's hole later on.  Also, the fact that soffit light means light goes down and may not light as large of area.  Which I am willing to live with, I imagine the 13W unit I picked at ~900 lumens should work when I have 3 in front of the garage and 2 on the porch.